# Triggering multiple translations from a single .zip

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is it possible to create multiple viewables from a single .zip upload? Our use case would be to create a viewable for the top level assembly, but then also create viewables of sub assemblies within the same zip.

Answer (score 0):

No direct way to achieve that, you can only trigger a translation against a single file upload. So you could upload the top level assembly as a zip and translate it, then upload separately each sub-assembly (could also be zips if you don't have a flat hierarchy) and translate them one by one or based on your needs.

You would also need to maintain relationships between the top level assembly and the sub-assemblies and their translated URNs on your own.

Hope that helps